# How to implement iterator of Btree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I'm thinking about how to implement an iterator of Btree?

for normal binary tree, I know there are tricks like threaded binary tree.

And for BTree+, since the value is all in leaf node, so a sibling pointer at the leaf node can do the trick.

But for BTree, I have no idea...

Comment: http://sunhe.jinr.ru/docs/root/html/TBtreeIter.html

Comment: What do you exactly mean by an iterator? do you mean you are trying to figure out best underlying data structures and collections to implement a Btree node?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you want a iterator for a btree. Maybe using stack to traverse the tree, keep track the index of current processing number on the btree node.

1. Create a iterator with a stack, and mark the root of current index is 0. Then push the root to stack, if current index of root has children, then push first child with current index 0 as well. Until you reach the leaf node.
2. When you call next method, you pop the node from stack, and you will return the number of current index. If the current btree node is not done yet, you just increase the current index by 1 and push to stack again.

There are some details I don't cover, but you basically get the idea how to implement it.